# Data interpretation between Matlab and Fortran

Tags: matlab, binary, fortran

I have some Fortran code that interprets a binary file.  Thanks to another question I asked I understand how the fortran code works but I need help changing it to MATLAB code.  Here is the Fortran code:

```
  IMPLICIT NONE

  DOUBLE PRECISION      SCALE

  CHARACTER*72          BLINE
  CHARACTER*72          DATA_FILE_FULL_NAME
  CHARACTER*6           DATA_FILE_NAME

  CHARACTER*4           CH4, CH4F
  REAL*4                RL4
  EQUIVALENCE          (RL4,CH4)

  CHARACTER*2           C2
  LOGICAL               LFLAG

  INTEGER*2             I2

  if(i2.eq.13881) LFLAG=.FALSE.

  c2='69'
  LFLAG=.TRUE.

  DATA_FILE_FULL_NAME='./'//DATA_FILE_NAME//'.DAT'

  OPEN(UNIT=20, FILE=DATA_FILE_FULL_NAME, ACCESS='DIRECT',
 .     RECL=72, status='OLD')
    READ(20,REC=1) BLINE
    CH4f=BLINE(7:10)
    call flip(4,lflag,ch4f,ch4)
    SCALE=RL4

  RETURN
  END  

c   ..................................................
    subroutine flip(n,lflag,ch1,ch2)
c   ..................................................

  integer*4        n, i
  character*(*)    ch1, ch2
  logical          lflag

  if(lflag) then
    do i=1,n
      ch2(i:i)=ch1(n-i+1:n-i+1)
    enddo
  else
    ch2=ch1
  endif

  return
  end
```

So basically (and I believe I understand this correctly) the Fortran code is checking the endianess and flipping it if the machine and the data don't match.  Additionally, the data is stored in memory in a place reserved for both CH4 and RL4 so by calling RL4 after defining CH4 the data is simply being cast to the REAL*4 type instead of the CHARACTER*4 type.  Now I need to figure out how to port this into Matlab.  I already have the capability to read in the raw data, but when I try various forms of interpreting it I always get the wrong answer.  So far I have tried:

```
fid=fopen(LMK_file,'r');
BLINE=fread(fid, 72,'char=>char');
CH4=BLINE(7:10);
SCALE=single(CH4(1)+CH4(2)+CH4(3)+CH4(4));

SCALE=int8(CH4(1)+256*int8(CH4(2))+256^2*int8(CH4(3))+256^3*int8(CH4(4));
```

in MATLAB but both give me the same wrong answer (which makes sense since its doing pretty much the same thing).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have your read the documentation for [`fread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fread.html)? In particular, for the [`machinefmt`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fread.html#input_argument_machinefmt) option, which allows you to [directly read in data with different edianness](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/importing-binary-data-with-low-level-i-o.html#br46pb3-1)?

Comment: I told you to forget about any 'ch4' for good reasond
 Best will be to follow @horchler, otherwise you can read a float and apply 'swapbytes' to it.

Comment: May be you can try [f2matlab](http://www.mathworks.it/matlabcentral/fileexchange/5260-f2matlab) to automatically convert this code.

Comment: @CitizenInsane "F2MATLAB LIMITATIONS: f2matlab can not handle some features of fortran90 yet. These include: can't handle difficult IO and read and write statements, goto (of course), equivalence, and pointers." This problem is all about I/O and `equivalence`

Comment: Sorry @VladimirF.  I did take your advice, just forgot to remove it from here.  @horchler.  I will try and take a look at the `machinefmt` option.

Comment: Hey guys, I figured it out thanks to your help @horchler and @VladamirF.  Instead of reading in the full line using `fread` and then parsing the data, I can read it in each chunk of data at a time into the format that I want it in.  For the specific question I can get rid of the `BLINE`and instead use something like:

`fid=fopen(LMK_file,'r');`
`IGNORE=fread(fid,6,'*char');`
`SCALE=fread(fid,1,'*float32','b');`  where the `'b'` indicates that the file is Big Endian.  If you want to make write this as an answer @horcler I will accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else who is looking for the answer to this question this is what I came up with thanks to the help in the comments.

```
fid=fopen(LMK_file,'r');  %open the file for reading
IGNORE=fread(fid,6,'*char');  %ignore the first 6 bytes.  This could also be performed using fseek
SCALE=fread(fid,1,'*float32','b');  %reading in the scale value as a floating point 32 bit number.
```

where the `b` indicates the Big endianess of the file.  By using the '*float32' option, fread automatically interprets the next 4 characters as a 32 bit floating point number.

This returns the correct value of scale from the given file.